# Azure Logic Apps Response HTTP Action Timing-Out After 60 Seconds

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a very simple Azure Logic App that makes a REST call to an SAP web server and translates the response JSON before sending a response back to the caller of the Logic App.  What is baffling me is that when the SAP call takes just over 1 minute, the Response action throws this error:

> **ActionResponseTimedOut.** The execution of template action 'Response' is
> failed: the client application timed out waiting for a response from
> service. This means that workflow took longer to respond than the
> alloted timeout value. The connection maintained between the client
> application and service will be closed and client application will get
> an HTTP status code 504 Gateway Timeout.

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits), the time-out HTTP calls is supposed to be 120 seconds (2 minutes).  Unless the Logic App history display is completely wrong, the entire Logic App never takes any where near 120 seconds to complete, it keeps failing at just over 60 seconds.

The `SAP GET CustomerCredit` action shown in the sample below is a [Logic Apps Customer Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/create-logic-apps-connector), not the built-in SAP action.  The Logic App is the current production version, *not* a preview version.

Am I doing something wrong?  I'd be fine if the Logic App actually timed-out after 2 minutes, but a 1 minute time-out is a bit extreme.

[image: HTTP Response Failing in 60 Seconds]

Comment: Hi, may I know if there is any update on this issue? Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your logic app shows `ActionResponseTimedOut` error even if it doesn't execute more than 120 seconds. I test it in my side and it works fine it the execution time less than 120 seconds. Here I can provide a workaround which may help with your problem.

**1.** Click "**...**" --> "**Setting**" of your "**Response**" action.

[image]

**2.** Enable "**Asynchronous Response**"

[image]

**3.** Then when you request the url of logic app, it will response with 202 accepted immediately. And in header of the response, we can find a "**Location**".

[image]

**4.** Request the url in "**Location**", it will response you with the result of the logic app(if the workflow is completed). If the workflow hasn't been completed, it will still response 202.

Comment: Thank you, Hury.  Unfortunately, the client app calling the Logic App doesn't know how to respond to an HTTP 202 response.