# Logic App returns a Gateway timeout error even after 30 secs

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I have a logic app that gets called from APIM > Function > Logic app > D365 (synchronous call based on http request trigger). When I call it the first time (after a day, or after a few hours), takes longer than usual (around 25-30 seconds) and results in a Gateway timeout error.

When I call it the second time, it usually completes the operation within 8-10 secs with no timeouts.

The error message is typical:
**The execution of template action 'Response_-_to_be_displayed' is failed: the client application timed out waiting for a response from service. This means that workflow took longer to respond than the alloted timeout value. The connection maintained between the client application and service will be closed and client application will get an HTTP status code 504 Gateway Timeout.**

While keeping the pattern synchronous, i don't think this is something that may cause a timeout issue. I have already checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67337416/azure-logic-apps-response-http-action-timing-out-after-60-seconds) and this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/301262/http-action-fails-with-timeout-in-logic-apps.html) too, but that's not a solution to my problem.
I want to keep the call synchronous (it's only a 25-30 sec call), is it something to do with an APIM policy or any settings in logic apps that can increase this?

Comment: is the APIM connected to an Azure Function? if yes, please have a look at the Azure function cold start time.

Comment: I can see the logic app cold start time, how can I check for the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you can increase the timeout in both logic app and APIM. In the case of APIM we implement a policy, which will dictate the timeout and in logic app it's app settings.
- But in case of APIM if the timeout is more than 240 sec then APIM won't be reliable, and it is advised to look for the implementation of the function.
- Now to increase the timeout in APIM we must set up the forward request policy and this policy has the attribute of timeout which you can set to your desired limit.
- Go to policy fragments in APIM and add the following to a policy

```
<forward-request timeout="60"/>
```

[image]

- Now regarding the logic-app, we can setup custom timeout by setting up application settings. For this you would need two setting one is threshold and other one is time out. you have to add these in app setting which is under configuration in portal for logic app.
- The settings are called

```
Runtime.FlowRetentionThreshold
```

and

```
Runtime.Backend.FlowRunTimeout
```

the values of these settings are in format `Days.hours:Minutes:seconds`  for example : 00.00:05:00 this one is for 5 minutes

[image]

- Also please check that your function is working properly as workflow timeout in logic apps and apim timeouts default value is more than the time it takes to execute a task according to you.

Refer this [msDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/edit-app-settings-host-settings?tabs=visual-studio-code#run-duration-and-history) on Logic app timeout

Refer this [msdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#ForwardRequest) on apim timeout.

Comment: the logic app timeout doc says , we need to update this in host settings. I have tried that but the timeout does not seem to be working. Can you confirm if it works for you in app settings?